# Running an exported Selenium test in C# WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

This may seem extremely simple but I cannot find documentation anywhere on how to actually run an exported Selenium test in my C# test project. The point of this is for my testers to create some tests using the IDE, then export them to C# files so that I can import them to my test project for regression testing throughout development. The test class has 2 lines that confuse me:

```
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test");//Test is the name of the exported test suite
suite.Add(new SimpleTest());//SimpleTest is the name of the test case
```

My question is how will it know what a "SimpleTest" object is or where to even get it? There is no path to the item or anything. I've never seen anything "just work" like this before. Also, if anyone has a better idea as far as approach I would appreciate the input.

Comment: Instead of exporting them as a suite, export them as test cases.

Comment: @Arran do you want to make that as an answer so I can mark it correct? I didn't even notice that option for some reason, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting them as a test suite, I'd export them as test cases, which in turn would export them as singular NUnit test cases.

From then you can use any kind of NUnit GUI (NUnit's own GUI, ReSharper, TeamCity etc) to run it.

Comment: Exporting as a test suite was my problem. Thanks a lot!